# curl, crowbar...passing to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, curl, xulrunner

```
<?php
function get_html($url)
{
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:10000/?url=' . $url . '&delay=3000&view=as-is');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec ($curl);
return $html;
}
?>
```

Im using this php code to access the html using crowbar...my question is, how would I pass the html to jquery for some processing (scraping).

My jquery starts with the document.ready(function(), would this work since crowbar actually loads the DOM in a browser?

This is some of my jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var title = $('title').text();
    $.ajax({
type:           "POST",
url:            "tosql.php",
data:           {title:title}
});
    });
```

Im only getting the title (for test purposes) because I pass this to php to be stored in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jQuery can manipulate everything in the DOM after it loads via the document.ready wrapper. If you need easier manipulation, have crowbar render data as an object or array inside of `<script>` tags. If you have more code to show I can give a more complete answer.

Comment: The problem is that the ajax is not executing?

Comment: no my problem is that I want to know how to pass the DOM that is retrieved by crowbar to my js (jquery)

Comment: You have to render the output of get_html in a page with jQuery included.